# Вес переменой

Tags: php

Не подскажете функцию для подсчета веса переменой(массива)

Comment: 3-4 кг будет.

Comment: Запросят же=))

Comment: @exec вот только почему то фраза сколько весит фильм или фотка никого не смущает... ;)

Comment: Я бы понял вопрос так же как @FLK, узнать сколько переменная оперативки жрет. Плюсую.

Comment: Да? И что это за чушь тогда получится? Зачем измерять массив в оперативке?

Comment: Ну если человек русский и имел бы ввиду длину массива, то как-то так бы и изъяснился. Кол-во элементов там.. завтра узнаем чего он хотел) или не узнаем. поровну...

Comment: @exec это масса ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$before=0;
$a='испытуемая переменная либо массив';
$before = memory_get_usage();
unset($a);
echo 'размер переменной составил: ',$before-memory_get_usage(),' байт';
```

**upd**
[[@Sh4dow](/users/465/sh4dow)](/users/465/sh4dow) на самом деле, 208 байт на $before, а echo бесплатно(я так понимаю из за того что строка не подгружается в память, а сразу выводится) да и есть еще несколько ньюансов, из критических то что php автоматически оптимизирует расход памяти и если переменные имеют одинаковое значение, то под последню выделяется память только для создания ссылки (208 байт) поэтому конструкция типа:

```
$a='испытуемая переменная либо массив';
$a=$b;
$before = memory_get_usage();
unset($a);
echo 'размер переменной составил: ',$before-memory_get_usage(),' байт';
```

вернет 208 байт для числа, 128 для строки либо массива.

**p.s.** а вот почему для числа выделяется столько памяти, для меня загадка.

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, это очень такой примерный размер будет? Типа -4 байта на `$before` и строки в echo.

Вообще мне кажется, единственный вариант для php - это дампить переменную в файл и смотреть его размер) И там как раз можно через pack записывать и еще по-всякому извращаться...

Comment: > Вообще мне кажется, единственный вариант для php - это дампить переменную в файл и смотреть его размер)

Так тоже не будет работать. Размер дампа и то сколько занимает переменная со всеми внутренними структурами в PHP слабо коррелируется.

Примерно можно узнать так:

    $before = memory_get_usage();
    $a = 'испытуемая переменная либо массив';
    echo memory_get_usage() - $before;

Но и это тоже не всегда применимо.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov либо определить $before до использования. и как я уже обновил ответ, просто присвоение другой переменной результата не даст, только создание уникального значения.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov имел в виду "объем данных". Т.е. в файле можно представить массив чисел как hex-строку, числа как строки и т.д. и только в этом случае у нас будет именно объем данных до байта, без оглядок на ссылки-кодировки и прочие пхп-шные костыли.

Comment: По поводу размеров аллокаций - [**http://habrahabr.ru/post/141093/**][1]

[1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/141093/

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, круто, спасибо

Comment: IMHO **реальный простой** способ оценить размеры (в Linux) это посмотреть в /proc/self/status значение VmRSS: - текущий резидентный размер программы в KB.

Все остальное это самообман. Обратите внимание **именно RSS, а не VmSize**.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос то:

```
sizeof - получает количество элементов в переменной.
```

Answer (score 0):

Вес - ахахахх =) Прикольно сказано: "Вес переменной" )))

Функция:

```
count(array)
```

тоже возвратит длину массива)

**P.S** С такими темпами скоро будут вопросы типа: "Как заглянуть в анус винде" =)))

Comment: а может имеется в виду что узнать сколько эта переменная места в оперативной памяти занимает?